# Is there a shortcut to open a folder in a Open File dialog?

Tags: macos

In an Open File dialog, I can press Return or Cmd-Down to go *into* a folder. But is there a key sequence to actually select the folder as the item to open? It seems I can only just use the mouse to press the Open button while the folder is highlighted.

(BBEdit is an example of an application in which I often want to open a folder.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Return` (with the ↩ symbol) *opens* the folder for browsing its contents (unless you're in column view). You need to press `Enter` instead. It's a different key, and its symbol is ⌤.

If you don't have that key on your keyboard, you can press `Fn-Return` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I so seldom use anything *but* column view that I was unaware of the distinction. You have my vote sir.

Answer (score 1):

Not all applications allow you to open multiple documents simultaneously but you can open an entire folder from a BBedit (Version 10.0.1) Open Dialog by using the *Column view*, selecting the folder you want to open, and hitting <kbd>return</kbd>.

[image: image of BBEdit Open Dialog Box]